# Run Gdal in paralel for list of raster files

Tags: python, raster, gdal

We have many raster files to be reduced to tiles.

The files are clipped using Gdal.Warp then merged.

Gdal.Warp has multiprocess parameter but it does not speed up much.

I want to use parallelism at the raster file level.
I am using python.

The problem is when using with `multiprocessing Pool`, the child process cannot find output_path.
`gdal.Warp(output_path, raster_path...`

I tried with `multiprocessing.pool ThreadPool`. Now I get the result. Looks like the time it takes is reduced by %10 with 10 threads. But I am not sure parallelism really took place.

There are 100 raster files and the program processes them in 23 seconds.

Comment: Parallelism isn't magic. You can't just get a 90% improvement on *any* task by using 10 threads. The fact that you got any improvement at all means that "parallelism took place.' Note that there is a difference between '10%' and '%10' (the former meaning ten percent and the latter being undefined)

Comment: Can you just start many single threaded processes, each one to handle one image?

Comment: @user30184 I am tried this. But I dont have tools to profile the process. So I am guessing that worked by %10 percent. 

The data is on disks. To gain speed using parallelism, raster-datasets must be on separated disks. Else they might race for resource and slow the process.
So it might be best to keep parallelism at gdals care.

Comment: You are doing the right thing by experimenting with your own hardware and use case. A few years ago I reached best speed by running gdalwarp binary in 4 separate command windows for running 4 CPUs at close to 100% load. With more processes the speed of the rotational hard disks became the limiting factor.

Comment: @GolD. HDD IO speed usually the first bottleneck. Upgrading to any SSD will significantly improve IO speed. If upgrading isn't an option then reading from one HDD and writing to another will somewhat improve the IO bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here because of very limited info regarding the code you are using but I think the quickest way to fix the multiprocess "cannot find output path" error is to add the output path in the function being called to run `gdal.Warp(output_path, raster_path...`.

Some background info.

`multiprocessing Pool` runs a copy of the code on however many `processes` are defined in the `Pool()` function and is limited by the number of CPU cores. Memory isn't shared between the different processes or cores so all the required information needs to be made available, either in a list if `.map()` is used or specified in the function being called.

Threading, runs on a CPU core and many threads can run on a single core. Threading shares memory so it is possible to use global variables. However, this can also result in variables with the same name being overwritten and return unexpected outputs. In addition, one of the most common errors I've seen using Threading to read multiple tiffs is a scanline offset error (or something along those lines). This happens when thread A reads data into RAM, Thread B overwrites that data in RAM, Thread A returns to RAM to read the data but find Thread B's data instead (it's slightly more complex behind the scenes but should give an idea of what is happen).

Multiprocessing is generally used for CPU intensive work and Threading is used for read/write (IO) intensive work (from disk or from the internet/network). Keep an eye on the PC/server resource monitor to see where the bottleneck is.